# SQL triple left join query across three databases

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm trying to run a query across three tables in three different databases. This query works but I'm pulling close to a billion records... Is there any solution to pull the distinct fields from smlog.requestor_type and arcust.maj_class for the following query?

```
SELECT
smreq.request_id AS ROIrequestID,
arcust.customer AS LAWcustID,
smlog.logid AS ESLlogID,
arcust.maj_class AS invoicetype,
smlog.requestor_type AS SMLrequestortype,
smlog.request_type as SMLrequesttype
FROM roi.sm_request_sp_data reqsp
LEFT JOIN smart.smlog@smartlog smlog ON smlog.logid = reqsp.logid
LEFT JOIN roi.sm_requests smreq ON smreq.request_id = reqsp.request_id
LEFT JOIN lawson.arcustomer@smart7 arcust ON arcust.customer = 
smreq.customer_id
WHERE smreq.ORIG_DT >= TO_DATE('2016/03/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
AND smreq.ORIG_DT <= TO_DATE('2016/03/02','yyyy/mm/dd')
GROUP BY smlog.requestor_type;
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Answer (score 0):

These are observations, not an answer

```
SELECT
      smreq.request_id     AS ROIrequestID
FROM roi.sm_request_sp_data reqsp
LEFT JOIN roi.sm_requests smreq ON reqsp.request_id = smreq.request_id

WHERE smreq.ORIG_DT >= TO_DATE('2016/03/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
AND smreq.ORIG_DT <= TO_DATE('2016/03/02', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

That LEFT JOIN is overridden completely by the where clause (any NULL produced from the left join is disallowed) so use an INNER JOIN instead.

For the where clause It isn't clear if you want one day's data ('2016/03/01') or 2 day's (both '2016/03/01'+ '2016/03/02'), If you are expecting just one day then don't use <= in the second predicate.

For the rest we really have no factual basis to make recommendations.

Comment: Not sure if INNER JOIN should be used instead of LEFT JOIN. If the OP actually meant LEFT JOIN, then the condition on date should be moved from the WHERE clause to the join (ON) condition.

Comment: That is true, but either way it isn't working as expected. I simply believe the inner join is more probable.

Comment: I didn't even read the original post; I was offering that as a general thought. If a WHERE clause defeats an outer join, the mistake may be either the join (doesn't need to be OUTER in the first place), OR the condition is in the wrong place. It happens often, especially to people converting from a life of Oracle proprietary join syntax to the SQL Standard syntax.

Comment: @mathguy the old sybase/sqlserver syntax was even worse imho ( `*=` `=*` etc.) ergh!